# Profiling multi-threaded and multi-processor program

Tags: multithreading, g++, profiling, mpi

My recently developed application uses multiple processors which communicate via the Message Passing Interface standard, while some parts involve several threads running asynchronously (`std::async`).

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 x86 with g++-4.6.3 in combination with openMPI.

Adding the `-p -g -pg` to the compiler flags and running gprof doesn't produce any useful output, it basically says everything was done in no time.

How to profile such programs?

Comment: Hybrid programs are best profiled with performance tools like Intel Trace Analyzer and Collector or VampirTrace/Vampir. Since both are commercial tools, you might also try Scalasca, although it presents higher level profiling data.

Comment: There are also tools for collecting traces of MPI calls which can be very useful. For example MPE: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/perfvis/software/MPE/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [Allinea MAP](http://www.allinea.com/products/map/) for this, developed by my employer. It profiles MPI applications and shows you where in your source code is costing your application time. There are some very useful graphs of memory usage, MPI communication and compute costs - and it allows you to zoom in on problem areas for performance easily.

You don't have to recompile your application to get started with it: it automatically adds profiling at runtime.

It is commercial software - but there is a 30 day trial.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-threaded programs, there is no need to bring out the big MPI profile guns. I use Intel's VTune, and it does an excellent job at profiling multiple threads. You can get a 30 day trial.